# Find best street for mapping point

Tags: google-maps, mapping, gis, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I know about mapping point on street vector, It's simple and I readed many link about this. for example :

[PostGIS](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html)

But my question is about how can I find best street for mapping? 
In other words I have one single point and multiple street for mapping!
(I would like implementation this by PostGIS because I have a many big streets!)

[image: Some other details]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Linear referencing in PostGIS ([ST_LineLocatePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html))

By doing the following:

1) create new event table.

2) join the events table back to your roads table and use the measure attribute to generate the spatial event points

A good example [You can find it here](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/linear_referencing.html)